# magento 2 custom product attribute won't save

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute, eav, custom-attributes

I am writing a Magento 2 module - am trying to get it to add a custom attribute to every product. My `Setup>InstallData.php` file is successfully adding the attribute to the `eav_attribute` table when installing the module, and the adminhtml is rendering the field as having `name=product[my_attribute]`, which I think means that it "accepts" the field as being a valid part of the model. However, when attempting to save the product with a value in the custom attribute, nothing is saved in the database.

here is my code:

```
<?php

// module namespace is 'Duel', module name is 'Gallery'
namespace Duel\Gallery\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, 
ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
/** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */

$eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

/**
* Add attributes to the eav/attribute
*/

$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'my_attribute', 
    [
        'type' => 'text',
        'backend' => '',
        'label' => 'My New Attribute',
        'input' => 'text',
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true
    ]
);
}
}
```

and here is the html in view>adminhtml>ui_component>product_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="attributes">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MY CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE</item>
        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
    </item>
</argument>  
<field name="my_attribute">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My new attribute</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

I briefly had it saving after manually changing a couple of fields of 'my_attribute' in the `eav_attribute` table, however I committed the code but stupidly didn't save the exact mysql database state and now can't get it to work again (upon testing that it creates a working form every time the module is installed).